# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh

I really do not know much about ssh. I only know how to type some commands to get into my machine in my office when I work from home. Today I got some updates on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, a new kernel plus other stuff. After that I tried to ssh as usual, but I keep receiving the following message:

```
nedu@nedu:~$ ssh -v user@server.de
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to server.de [134.2.76.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/nedu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I tried to repeat from the older kernel version, but no luck.
I read a lot on Google as well as on this site, but there are many many proposed solutions which have configuration files changed. Before doing that, without really knowing what I am doing, I want to try to get a personal answer. How can I fix this? And first of all, how do I know that the problem concerns my home machine, and not the server I am trying to ssh?

Comment: can you `ping` that IP address? What about `telnet 134.2.76.10 22`?

Comment: It seems that ping doesnt ping, while 'telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out'. This mean that it is a problem of the server connection, right?